# Reference request: $f_n \to f$ uniformly implies that $\inf (f_n) \to \inf (f)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

As the title says, I am looking for a *reference* to a proof for the following result: let $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open and let $f_n: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that each $f_n$ is bounded on $U$. Assume that $f_n \to f$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$ to a function $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, $$\inf_U(f_n) \to \inf_U(f) $$ as $n \to \infty$. Alternatively, the condition that $U$ is open and that each $f_n$ is bounded can be replaced by assuming $U$ is compact instead.

I know this is a rather elementary result, but I haven't been able to find a source in which this is proven explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result which has nothing to do with continuity, or compactness of the domain. It's true simply by how uniform convergence of a sequence of functions is defined and how infimum works. So, the following more general statement is true:

> Let $A$ be a non-empty set, $\{f_n:A\to \Bbb{R}\}_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions, and $f:A\to \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly as $n\to \infty$. Then,
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\inf_{x\in A}f_n(x)\right] = \inf_{x\in A}f(x).
> \end{align}

---

**Case $1$: $\inf\limits_{x\in A}f(x)$ is finite**

To prove this statement, let $\epsilon>0$. Then , by hypothesis of uniform convergence, there exists $N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ and all $x\in A$, we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ (pay close attention to the quantifiers, and the order they appear in). I claim this same $N$ will "work" to prove the claim. We can rewrite this inequality as
\begin{align}
f(x)-\epsilon \leq f_n(x) \leq f(x) + \epsilon \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Clearly, this implies that (for all $n\geq N$ and all $x\in A$)
\begin{align}
\inf_{x\in A}f(x) - \epsilon \leq f_n(x) \leq f(x)+\epsilon
\end{align}
Since this is true for all $n\geq N$ and for all $x\in A$, what this says is that for all $n\geq N$, $\inf\limits_{x\in A}f(x)$ is a lower bound for the set of numbers $\{f_n(x)\}_{x\in A}$. Hence, for all $n\geq N$, and all $x\in A$
\begin{align}
\inf_{x\in A}f(x) - \epsilon \leq \inf_{x\in A}f_n(x) \leq f(x)+\epsilon
\end{align}
Similarly (think about which number is a lower bound for which set of numbers), it follows that for all $n\geq N$,
\begin{align}
\inf_{x\in A}f(x) - \epsilon \leq \inf_{x\in A}f_n(x) \leq \inf_{x\in A}f(x)+\epsilon
\end{align}
Hence, for all $n\geq N$, we have $\left|\inf\limits_{x\in A}f_n(x) - \inf\limits_{x\in A}f(x)\right| \leq \epsilon$. This completes the proof.

---

**Remark about Case $1$.**

Note that while I may have written things in a slightly longer fashion to make things more explicit, with some practice, you should be able to justify immediately going directly from $(*)$ to (for all $n\geq N$)
\begin{align}
\inf_{x\in A}f(x)-\epsilon \leq \inf_{x\in A}f_n(x) \leq \inf_{x\in A}f(x) + \epsilon
\end{align}
which of course completes the proof of this case.

---

**Case $2$: $\inf\limits_{x\in A} f(x) = - \infty$**.

I leave this to you :)

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to downvote your answer. As I already said, I do not want a proof for this result (as I know how to prove it myself as a matter of fact). I want a book/lecture notes in which this result is already proven, so I can reference it in another context (and not claim that I have discovered it, or bother writing a proof).

Comment: @C_M ok my bad then. Unfortunately I couldn't find any reference which proves this result; so if you want I'll delete this answer.

Comment: " I want a book/lecture notes in which this result is already proven, so I can reference it in another context (and not claim that I have discovered it, or bother writing a proof)" in many possible versions of that context you don't need a reference or a proof - a triviality like this you can simply state without proof if the intended audience is mathematical adults...